# How to validate two password fields with Joi in TS React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, joi

I am building a reusable form component with TypeScript, let's call it `AbstractForm` for now. It is designed to be inherited by other components like `LoginForm`, `RegisterForm` and so on, let's say I am working on some `DerivedForm` component. To validate the fields I am using `Joi`. The derived component only has to supply the domain model (Joi validation schema) and the submit method. 
Everything works great and validates perfectly, except when I want to use two password fields, and the second password is checked to match the first one via `Joi.string().valid(this.state.data.password)`. It never passes the validation even when both passwords are identical, Joi still throws an error saying that they are not. And I can't even think of a reason why. Can someone suggest what is the cause of this behaviour?
 
I am not using `Joi.ref('password')` instead because fields are validated in isolation with every `onChange` event (method `validateProperty()` in `AbstractForm` does it).

This is the Schema interface defined in the `AbstractForm` module:

```
export interface Schema {
  [key: string]: Joi.Schema;
}
```

This is my schema in the `DerivedForm`:

```
schema: Schema = {
name: Joi.string()
  .required()
  .min(1)
  .label('Name'),
email: Joi.string()
  .required()
  .email()
  .min(5)
  .label('Email'),
password: Joi.string()
  .required()
  .min(8)
  .label('Password')
  .error(
    errors => 'Passwords should match and have at least 8 characters.'
  ),
repeatPassword: Joi.string()
  .valid(this.state.data.password)
  .required()
  .label('Password')
  .error(
    errors => 'Passwords should match and have at least 8 characters.'
  ),
};
```

And this is how these fields are validated inside the `AbstractForm`:

```
validateProperty = (name: string, value: string) => {
  const property = { [name]: value };
  const propSchema: Schema = { [name]: this.schema[name] };
  const { error } = Joi.validate(property, propSchema);
  return error ? error.details[0].message : null;
};

handleChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  const { name, value } = e.currentTarget;

  const data = { ...this.state.data };
  data[name] = value;

  const errors = { ...this.state.errors };
  const errorMessage = this.validateProperty(name, value);
  if (errorMessage) errors[name] = errorMessage;
  else delete errors[name];

  this.setState({ data, errors });
};
```

I am also aware that `this.setState()` as well as the new `useState()` calls are asynchronous, but we are talking about validating against a different field here, so it should not be a problem. 
I can add all the code for both modules if needed. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the valid reference to the first password field is generated only when the component is mounted. To update the reference, you can add this piece of code:

```
  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.schema.repeatPassword = Joi.string()
      .min(8)
      .valid(this.state.data.password)
      .required()
      .label('Password')
      .error(
        errors => 'Passwords should match and have at least 8 characters.'
      );
  }
```

...so it could remember the new "valid" value. I think that this is happening because I am using class component, not functional component. And with functional component the schema would update every render by itself.